# How to make this jump across in Testchamber 16 in Chapter 8?

Tags: portal-2

I managed to get rid of those nasty turrets on the right of the entrance of the Testchamber 16 in Chapter 8:

[image]

But I'm can't seem to figure out how to get to the exit on the other side.

[image]

I've tried bouncing there, but the end result was me falling in an endless void... So any suggestions?

Comment: That was probably the hardest test chamber. It took me about 30 minutes to get rid of the robots (maybe more? lost my timing) and ten more seconds to get to the exit. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, no kidding.  I thought I was going to go crazy hunting for the missing box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to gain height, fall into a portal through the now exposed diagonally aligned  panel, jump onto the blue gel and reach the exit.

Basically, from your second picture, just place a portal on that panel. The rest will take care of itself.

Comment: Obviously I hadn't tried bouncing like that, silly me :-)